# How can I cd into a directory that i created before in my batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

it's the first time that I write a little script in batch, I need to create a folder named like the date, then I want to go in that directory and run the dump of my database. Here my code:

```
cd C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\db_backup

FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do mkdir %%a-%%b-%%c

cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin

mysqldump -uroot -proot emc > C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\db_backup\*here goes the folder created before*\backup.sql
```

I know that probably is a stupid question, but i never work whith batch.
Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 1):

The date format changes by region settings and machine - it's wiser to use Wmic to get it in a stable format.

But this should work:

```
cd /d "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\db_backup"

FOR /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do set d=%%a-%%b-%%c

md "%d%"

cd /d "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"

mysqldump -uroot -proot emc > "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\db_backup\%d%\backup.sql"
```